# Pivot BigQuery table using multiple rows

Tags: google-bigquery, pivot, bigquery-udf

In order to pivot my big query table, I found this code

```
SELECT 'SELECT id, ' || 
   STRING_AGG(
      'MAX(IF(key = "' || key || '", value, NULL)) as `' || key || '`'
   ) 
   || ' FROM `project.dataset.table` GROUP BY id ORDER BY id'
FROM (
  SELECT key 
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY key
  ORDER BY key
```

But even if I apply `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` function, it returns a string of the code above.
What did I missed in that function ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(
SELECT 'SELECT id, ' || 
   STRING_AGG(
      'MAX(IF(key = "' || key || '", value, NULL)) as `' || key || '`'
   ) 
   || ' FROM `project.dataset.table` GROUP BY id ORDER BY id'
FROM (
  SELECT key 
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY key
  ORDER BY key
)  
);
```

Comment: I applied your script, it runs ! But how could I display the table then ?

Comment: If you are in Console UI - in Results Panel you should find `VIEW RESULTS`  Links/Buttons. Just click on the last one

Comment: Ok I found it ! I got two jobs, one that contains the query and the other the display of the table. Finally how could I create a table from the result ?

Comment: Actually, I had an ERROR RUNNING QUERY on that. The script process 17.3GiB when running.

Comment: Your original question is fully answered. if you have new questions - post them as a separate posts so we will be happy to help further! :o) When posting new question - please provide all details related to the new issue ...